# Maven throwing error with Grails 2.3.7 and Tiles 3.0.3

Tags: grails

When I include tiles-core 3.0.3 in the pom of my grails 2.3.7 project I get.

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2$RootHandler.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V" the class loader (instance of org/grails/launcher/RootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelper2$RootHandler, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type andler.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V used in the signature
```

I am assuming a dependency is getting overridden by an older one but I have no idea which. Any ideas? I tried going back to 2.0.1 on tiles and I still get the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        <!-- IMPORTANT -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```